# An Hob ERROR: Timeout while attempting to communicate with bitbake server

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto

I used hob edited recipes (added iptables,curl,python,tar..)  based on image  core-image-full-cmdline. Then build packages,and all succeeded. When I build Image,occured an error:

```
Hob found an error
hob Exception-
```

And the message in the log file like below:

```
ERROR: Timeout while attempting to communicate with bitbake server
```

Can someone tell me what the **bitbake server** is ?
I would welcome any helpful suggestions on how to handle it.
Thanks a lot!

**The full log file is here**:

```
NOTE: Resolving any missing task queue dependencies

Build Configuration:
BB_VERSION        = "1.26.0"
BUILD_SYS         = "x86_64-linux"
NATIVELSBSTRING   = "Ubuntu-14.04"
TARGET_SYS        = "arm-poky-linux-gnueabi"
MACHINE           = "qemuarm"
DISTRO            = "poky"
DISTRO_VERSION    = "1.8"
TUNE_FEATURES     = "arm armv5 thumb dsp"
TARGET_FPU        = "soft"
meta              
meta-yocto        
meta-yocto-bsp    = "<unknown>:<unknown>"

NOTE: Preparing RunQueue
NOTE: Executing SetScene Tasks
NOTE: Executing RunQueue Tasks
NOTE: Tasks Summary: Attempted 2394 tasks of which 2394 didn't need to be rerun and all succeeded.
ERROR: Unknown event: error
NOTE: Resolving any missing task queue dependencies

Build Configuration:
BB_VERSION        = "1.26.0"
BUILD_SYS         = "x86_64-linux"
NATIVELSBSTRING   = "Ubuntu-14.04"
TARGET_SYS        = "arm-poky-linux-gnueabi"
MACHINE           = "qemuarm"
DISTRO            = "poky"
DISTRO_VERSION    = "1.8"
TUNE_FEATURES     = "arm armv5 thumb dsp"
TARGET_FPU        = "soft"
meta              
meta-yocto        
meta-yocto-bsp    = "<unknown>:<unknown>"

NOTE: Preparing RunQueue
NOTE: Executing SetScene Tasks
NOTE: Executing RunQueue Tasks
NOTE: Running noexec task 1870 of 2835 (ID: 4, /home/fuxy/Documents/poky-fido-13/build/recipes/images/core-image-full-cmdline-edited-20150730-132403.bb, do_fetch)
NOTE: Running noexec task 1871 of 2835 (ID: 0, /home/fuxy/Documents/poky-fido-13/build/recipes/images/core-image-full-cmdline-edited-20150730-132403.bb, do_unpack)
NOTE: Running noexec task 1873 of 2835 (ID: 1, /home/fuxy/Documents/poky-fido-13/build/recipes/images/core-image-full-cmdline-edited-20150730-132403.bb, do_patch)
NOTE: Running task 2832 of 2835 (ID: 8, /home/fuxy/Documents/poky-fido-13/build/recipes/images/core-image-full-cmdline-edited-20150730-132403.bb, do_populate_lic)
NOTE: Running task 2833 of 2835 (ID: 7, /home/fuxy/Documents/poky-fido-13/build/recipes/images/core-image-full-cmdline-edited-20150730-132403.bb, do_rootfs)
NOTE: recipe core-image-full-cmdline-edited-20150730-132403-1.0-r0: task do_populate_lic: Succeeded
NOTE: recipe core-image-full-cmdline-edited-20150730-132403-1.0-r0: task do_rootfs: Succeeded
NOTE: Running noexec task 2835 of 2835 (ID: 11, /home/fuxy/Documents/poky-fido-13/build/recipes/images/core-image-full-cmdline-edited-20150730-132403.bb, do_build)
NOTE: Tasks Summary: Attempted 2835 tasks of which 2829 didn't need to be rerun and all succeeded.
ERROR: Unknown event: error
ERROR: Timeout while attempting to communicate with bitbake server
ERROR: Timeout while attempting to communicate with bitbake server
ERROR: Timeout while attempting to communicate with bitbake server
```

Answer (score 2):

This too old question, but I  just faced the same problem and here how I fixed it,

```
rm -rf bitbake.lock
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem, while building yocto in a virtual machine. Apparently, the problem was lack of RAM. It went away, when I have the VM 4GB RAM instead of 2GB.